# Python @property.setter

Tags: python, cpython, python-decorators

The basic way of creating decorators is

```
def my_decorator(f):
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something using f
        pass
    return _f

@my_decorator
def f(...):
    ...
```

But that way you cannot define decorators like `@property.setter`, because the name of the property (and thus the name of the decorator) is different every time.

How is it `@property.setter` defined then? Is it possible to do something similar in Python, or is it built-in feature available only from C (implementation) level?

Comment: Related: [Python, how does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html):

```
 class Descriptor(object):
   def __get__(self, instance, _type=None):
     pass
   def __set__(self, obj, value):
     pass
```

You are free to implement things as you see fit. The `property` decorator is just an instance of a descriptor (more or less) and you can see how they'd implement it in the documents describing this item.

Here's an example:

```
  class _Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, caller, instance):
      self.caller = caller
      self.instance = instance

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print "I've been wrapped!"
      return self.caller(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)

  class Accouncer(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
      self.method = method

    def __get__(self, instance, _type=None):
      return _Wrapper(self.method, instance)

  def vocal(func):
    return Accouncer(func)

  class Ha(object):
    @vocal
    def stuff(self):
      return 1
```